# How can I create a Maplotlib Plot in D3.JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can create a polar chart which is like a clock that shows 24 hours of data using the following script:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the dummy data
hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['DVALUE'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['DVALUE2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['SVALUE'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['SVALUE2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df = df[(df.ID==1)]

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour*60+df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute

# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24*60, endpoint=False)

# print(len(hour_minute))
r = df.SVALUE.tolist()
r2 = df.SVALUE2.tolist()
s = df.DVALUE.tolist()
s2 = df.DVALUE2.tolist()
theta = df.SVALUE # power = SBP
area = r
colors = r

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r, color='red', label='SBP') # markers are controlled with 'o-'
ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r2, color='red', label='SBP2')

ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s, color='blue', label='DVALUE') # markers are controlled with 'o-'
ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s2, color='blue', label='DVALUE2')

ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r, r2, interpolate=True, color='red', alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s, s2, interpolate=True, color='blue', alpha=0.3)

# clock labels
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))
ax.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.1), fontsize=8)

# make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 180)

# place 0 at the top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)

plt.show()
```

How can I create the exact same plot in D3.JS? I tried creating the plot using the following JS code, but even labels seems like meessed up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3 Polar Bar Chart</title>
    <style>
        #chart {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
        // Data
        var data = [
            { "Time": "16:15", "Feed_Num": 2 },
            { "Time": "19:50", "Feed_Num": 2 },
            { "Time": "20:15", "Feed_Num": 2 },
            { "Time": "21:00", "Feed_Num": 1 },
            { "Time": "23:30", "Feed_Num": 2 }
        ];

        // Convert time to radians
        function convertToRadians(time) {
            var [hour, minute] = time.split(':').map(Number);
            var totalMinutes = hour * 60 + minute;
            return (2 * Math.PI * totalMinutes) / (24 * 60);
        }

        // Convert data
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.Time = convertToRadians(d.Time);
        });

        // Create SVG container
        var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 };
        var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var svg = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        // Create polar plot
        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + margin.left) + "," + (height / 2 + margin.top) + ")");

        // Define scale
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI])
            .range([0, radius]);

        // Create bars
        var bars = g.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.Time); })
            .attr("height", 10)
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.Time * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"; });

        // Label names
        var ticks = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23'];

        // Add radial labels
        var labels = g.selectAll("text")
            .data(ticks)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + (i * 360 / ticks.length - 90) + ")translate(" + (radius + 10) + ",0)"; });

        // Bars to the wall
        bars.attr("y", -bars.node().getBBox().height / 2);

        // Legend
        var legend = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + 20) + "," + (margin.top + 20) + ")");

        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", 10)
            .attr("fill", "red");

        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 15)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .text("Day 1");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I create polar chart in D3 so that output plot have a radial scale from 0 to 180. Its labels should be from 0 to 23 like clock for 24 hours data.This circular plot should show changes of a column over time with minute precision. I already implemented this in matplotlib, but I cannot go any step further in D3. Any help is appreciated.